# STD::COUT affecting functionality of program

Tags: c++, cout

So I am in the middle of wring a function for a much larger project. Its messy at the moment, but I am experiencing some very strange behaviour.

The portion of my code where the behaviour originates is shown below:

```
while(rw < (startY + 3)) {
        while(cl < (startX + 3)) {
            if(board[rw][cl] == '*'){ 

                char poss[9] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
                unsigned int totalcount = 0;
                unsigned int possibilities = 0;
                unsigned int possibleRow = 0;
                unsigned int possibleCol = 0;
                unsigned int lastCheck = 0;

                for(unsigned int alpha = 0; alpha < 9; alpha++){
                    if (testGrid('r', poss[alpha], rw) == true) { totalcount++; }
                    if (testGrid('c', poss[alpha], cl) == true) { totalcount++; }
                    if (testGrid('s', poss[alpha], 0) == true) { totalcount++; }
                    if(totalcount == 0) { possibilities++; }
                    totalcount = 0;
                }

                std::cout << possibilities << " possibilities" << std::endl;

                if(possibilities == 1) {
                    possibleRow = rw;
                    possibleCol = cl;

                    for(unsigned int alpha = 0; alpha < 9; alpha++){
                        if (testGrid('r', poss[alpha], possibleRow) == true) { lastCheck++; }
                        if (testGrid('c', poss[alpha], possibleCol) == true) { lastCheck++; }
                        if (testGrid('s', poss[alpha], 0) == true) { lastCheck++; }
                        if(lastCheck == 0) { board[rw][cl] = poss[alpha]; }
                        lastCheck = 0;
                    }
                }
                possibilities = 0;
            }
            cl++;
        }
        rw++;
        cl = startX;
    }
```

The output of the entire program solves one small square of a sudoku grid (infant stages).
But if i comment out the line:
    std::cout << possibilities << " possibilities" << std::endl;
the output is different (other than the obvious lack of output. shown below:

[image]

Obvious this is undesired behaviour. But can anyone explain it?

pastebin: [the code](http://pastebin.com/ERpf0cy3)
pastebin: [the input file](http://pastebin.com/3uSBx9tv)

Comment: I can't see why that would be happening. Could you pastebin a full code sample that I can run for myself?

Comment: I doubt we can figure it out unless you show us your whole code — or, even better, a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I've seen something similar resulting from reading a portion of the stack that wasn't truly allocated and was being overwritten as part of a printf call in C. Make sure testGrid doesn't have any botched pointer arithmetic, or io into areas it doesn't own.

Comment: You are indeed having some trouble with memory that has been unallocated. My best guess is that your testGrid has gone out of scope, but you are keeping a pointer to it (which works unless some other memory coincidentally needs it).

Comment: @Max added pastebin links

Comment: I Ran a DrMemory on it and the only issues were:
3 unique, 3 total potential handle leak(s)

Comment: You are not allocating or even intializing your `board` variable anywhere at all. Consider making a constructor for your class.

Comment: @Rhys `But if i comment out the line:` What debugging have you done so far?  You know when those bad lines are produced, so why not place a breakpoint in the code where those lines are produced and inspect the variable(s)?

Comment: Can you pos the code here, and not link to external sites which will go away eventually, making this question useless for future readers?

Comment: @sanchises Allocated on line 15, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @MikePrecup No, you **defined** it at line 15. You never initialized or allocated it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe (can't test, unfortunately, have no C++ compiler on this machine) that the issue is coming from line 133, where you never give a value to `count`. If this stack variable is left alone, it will continue to be 1, and the test will pass every subsequent time on line 149. The cout creates several stackframes on top of the current stack, overwriting that value in memory and changing your results. Change line 133 to something like

```
unsigned int count = 0;
```

Note that you do also have a count variable in scope already when this is declared; perfectly legal, but I just want to point it out in case the intent was to be using that one, and not making a new one. If you do want to use that one instead, remove line 133.

Declaring a primitive and using it when you may not have given it a value is a recipe for odd behavior. You have no idea what's in the memory given to that variable, so its value could theoretically be completely arbitrary. It's possible it could be 1 to begin with, which is what's happening here, since the 1 was left over in memory from previous calls to the function.

For posterity, in case pastebin (God forbid) eventually dies, this is the troubling section:

```
unsigned int startY = 0;
unsigned int startX = 0;
unsigned int count; //line 133

startY = (num / 3) * 3;
startX = (num % 3) * 3;

unsigned int rw = startY;
unsigned int cl = startX;

while(rw < (startY + 3)) {
    while(cl < (startX + 3)) {
        if(board[rw][cl] == ident){ count = 1; }
        cl++;
    }
    rw++;
    cl = startX;
}
if(count == 1){ //line 149
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Same behaviour as when you were printing with printf() and in the same time saving your ass from some segfaults. I remember that

Answer (score -1):

You have not initialized your `board` variable. Depending on your compiler version, you should change the line defining it to

```
board[9][9] = { {0} };
```

But, more likely, you will have to create a constructor as follows

```
grid() : board{ {0} } { */empty constructor*/};
```

Finally, I would like to point out that classes in c++ should be PascalCase by convention; this helps clarify that `Grid` is a constructor, as functions would never start with a capital.

Comment: -1 All that does is zero it, it was already initialized. Definition is allocation for statically allocated arrays. This doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Creating the constructor as in your second code snippet just gives me errors.